# Create a ball with a random number in the middle (html canvas and javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im trying to create a ball which generates a different random number in the middle every time the function's called. This is my code for creating a ball object but i have no clue where to put the Math.random method and how to actually draw the number in the middle. Have you got any idea? Below is my JavaScript external file's code:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var ball = { 
      radius:50,
      x:200,
      y:150,
      color:"#00F",
      draw:function() {
        var arcStartAngle=0;
        var arcEndAngle=2*Math.PI;

        ctx.fillStyle=this.color
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,arcStartAngle,arcEndAngle);
        ctx.fill();
      }
 }
ball.draw();
```

Comment: What do you want to do? May be you do not need canvas for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `draw` function generate a random number and draw it on the screen after the ball:

```
  draw:function() {
    ...
    // Ball drawing stuff  
    ...  
    // Draw number in the middle
    ctx.fillStyle= "#FFF";
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    ctx.fillText(randNum,this.x,this.y);
  }
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/kc31c0bk/)

That is if you want the drawing of a number be apart of the ball. Otherwise you can move the code to some sort of `drawRandomNumber()` function and call that.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
draw:function(){
      var arcStartAngle=0;
      var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
      ...
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesnt work.I think there should be another property in the object which holds a random integer.Thanks for your answer though

Answer (score 0):

```
      createRandomNo: function() {
          var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
          ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
          ctx.fillText(number, this.x, this.y);
      },
```

and call createRandomNo() function after ball is drawn.